# Directory listener in Java

Tags: java, directory, filesystems, listener

I have an application in which I want to listen to any changes made to a particular directory.  The application should ping me as soon as there are any files added, deleted or updated in that directory.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)

> JNotify is a java library that allow java application to listen to file
>   system events, such as: File created
>   File modified File renamed File
>   deleted Supported platforms
>
> Windows (2000 or newer) Windows notes
>   Linux with INofity support (2.6.14 or
>   newer) Linux notes Mac OS X (10.5 or
>   newer) Mac OS notes

**More Info :**

Download JNotify from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnotify/files/jnotify/jnotify-0.93/jnotify-lib-0.93.zip/download)

Extract the zip, put .dll/.so according to platform in your lib path. and create a class provide `jnotify-0.93.jar` in class path.

Sample code:

```
package org.life.java.stackoverflow.questions;

import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify;
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotifyListener;

/**
 *
 * @author Jigar
 */
public class JNotifyDemo {

    public void sample() throws Exception {
        // path to watch
        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");

        // watch mask, specify events you care about,
        // or JNotify.FILE_ANY for all events.
        int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED
                | JNotify.FILE_DELETED
                | JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED
                | JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;

        // watch subtree?
        boolean watchSubtree = true;

        // add actual watch
        int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new Listener());

        // sleep a little, the application will exit if you
        // don't (watching is asynchronous), depending on your
        // application, this may not be required
        Thread.sleep(1000000);

        // to remove watch the watch
        boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID);
        if (!res) {
            // invalid watch ID specified.
        }
    }

    class Listener implements JNotifyListener {

        public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName,
                String newName) {
            print("renamed " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);
        }

        public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("modified " + rootPath + " : " + name);
        }

        public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("deleted " + rootPath + " : " + name);
        }

        public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("created " + rootPath + " : " + name);
        }

        void print(String msg) {
            System.err.println(msg);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new JNotifyDemo().sample();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar: LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_4s8ywsvyukghK0uDxRop
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_4s8ywsvyukghK0uDxRop
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\output1295531079119
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
deleted C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001ea9
created C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eae
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eae
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eae
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\output1295531079119
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Session
deleted C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001ea8
created C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eaf
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eaf
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eaf
```

Comment: When i run the program it gives me exceptionError loading library, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system32\Wbem;\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\putty;C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Unsa

Comment: `Extract the zip, put .dll/.so according to platform in your lib path.`

Comment: yes i did that i put the jar in class path and dll in lib folder as am using windows7.Also am using the netbeans IDE for development.

Comment: you need to put dll in system32 folder for windows machine

Comment: Have you used this api on mac... what the system files we would be using in that case?

Comment: just do `System.out.println(Sysgtem.getProperties("library.path"));` it will return list of paths from where system reads for library. you can choose any appropriate dir

Comment: usually you can also just leave the dll where you want and launch java with java -Djava.library.path=dlls -classpath .....

Comment: @JigarJoshi I did not understand the removing part. boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID); what does it mean? When we call removeWatch() does it remove, if so, how it continues watching? This part for me is confusing

Comment: in this example it is live due to sleep(), if you want to keep it live then don't call remove watch unless you want to really remove the watch and make your program executing

Comment: If one consider [number of reported and unresolved issues](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=154048&atid=790218) and how old code is (even if you look [here](https://github.com/fhuberts/jnotify)) then probably if you can you should go and use [Watcher api from java7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) or if polling is fine for you then try [commons-io](http://andreinc.net/2012/06/30/writing-a-simple-file-monitor-in-java-using-commons-io/).

Answer (score 27):

Since Java 1.7 you can use the [Watch Service API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to register for directory events. It is part of Java's [New I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) (NIO) library and does not require any additional resources. An example how to use the API can be found in the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

After registering the WatchService you can retrieve events for the target path like this:

```
for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
             // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
            Path name = ev.context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);

            // print out event
            System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);
        }
```

Comment: This should become the (new) accepted answer. `nio` has been available for a while now and meddling with adding some .dll/.so should not be the go-to answer imo.

Comment: Can we use this for remote folder?

Answer (score 3):

Jnotify for file notification in java. Code sample

```
   public void sample() throws Exception {
        // path to watch    
        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");    
        // watch mask, specify events you care about,    
        // or JNotify.FILE_ANY for all events.    
        int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED  |                
        JNotify.FILE_DELETED  |                
        JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED |                
        JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;    
        // watch subtree?    boolean watchSubtree = true;    
        // add actual watch    
        int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new Listener());    
        // sleep a little, the application will exit if you    
        // don't (watching is asynchronous), depending on your    
        // application, this may not be required    
        Thread.sleep(1000000);    
        // to remove watch the watch    
        boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID);    
        if (!res) {      
            // invalid watch ID specified.    
            }  
        }  
    class Listener implements JNotifyListener 
    {    
        public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName,        
                String newName) {      
            print("renamed " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);    }    
        public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) 
        {      print("modified " + rootPath + " : " + name);    }    
        public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {      
            print("deleted " + rootPath + " : " + name);    }    
        public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {      
            print("created " + rootPath + " : " + name);    }    
        void print(String msg) {      
            System.err.println(msg);    }  
        }
```

Comment: When i run the program it gives me exceptionError loading library, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system32\Wbem;\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\putty;C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Unsa

Comment: 1.- Right click on the Project
2.- Properties
3.- Click on RUN
4.- VM Options: java -Djava.library.path="your_path"
5.- for example in my case: java -Djava.library.path=</Users/Lexynux/NetBeansProjects/NAO/libs>
6.- Ok