# How to poll directory to check whether new file is added?

Tags: java, directory

I want to poll a directory to check whether new file is added to the directory.  If any new file is added I want to read that file.

Can anybody give me an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 16):

- Java 7 has a [file watcher API](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes)
- [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) will do it as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Java 7, you can use the filesystem watch service (a new feature in Java 7).

See [Oracle's tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) that explains how to use it.

Otherwise (if you're using an older Java version) you can use a library such as [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/). Look at the package `org.apache.commons.io.monitor` - it has classes to check for changes in files and directories.

Answer (score 3):

[jNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) would be useful,

**See Also**

- [directory-listener-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941869/directory-listener-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Why not Apache Camel?

Here's what the code will look like:

```
from("file://pollingfolder?delete=true").to("bean:handleOrder");
```

That reads the files from "pollingfolder", deletes it upon read, and sends it to a bean called "handleOrder". Just in one line!

There's an easy way to configure it with Spring-boot automagically if you use Spring, but it can be used in plain Java as well.

Source: [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html)