# Java periodically returning the newest files in subdirectories into one array

Tags: java

I have a root folder, and it contains a number of sub-directories, and each sub-directory contains only xml files (no other directories).. I need to make a program that returns the newest files added in (in all of the sub-directories) to be able to send them to ftp subscribers..

what's the best way to do that ?

I am able to look through one directory and sort all its files but I don't know how to do it for multiple sub-directories..and I need only the newest files, if i return all the files it will slow down the program.

Also, I need this program to be executed periodically, do I have to include this in the method it self, or create an other class for that ?

Comment: The link in @dystroy's answer contains a code sample for traversing the subdirectories of a directory.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344331/how-to-poll-directory-to-check-whether-new-file-is-added

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking periodically, you can be notified when the directory's content changes, using the new nio Watch Service API. This is efficient as it uses low level system notification API.

Oracle Documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many questions here:

First, about the directory tree traversal. If you're able to read one directory, you're able to read ever one of them. You will need some sort of iterative or recursive functionality that reads through a directory listing of files. For each file that is a directory itself, you call the function again using it as a new root. There is a isDirectory() method in the File class, for that.

As for the recognition of new files, you need to keep the old values (of a previous program run) and compare them to the new ones. Or you could rely on the files modification time and compare them to the time of the last run. Any file newer to this date would be a new one or an old file that was modified after the last run.

As for having it run periodically, it depends. You could set it as an operating system service, with serviceWrapper, or you could run it in a container, or even run it as standalone and have this function called periodically, after some delay or waiting or sleeping. There are too many options and too few information to even suggest what would be best. But it will be something like that, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Well what i would do...

First store the current time stamp in a file which you will read on next invocations this will let the program know when it was last executed.

Now read the time stamp and include only files which have the

`file.lastModified() > lastTimeStampOfRun` and return them.

For scanning all the files and directory you can simply use java IO.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The way to get the list of files is to use `File.listFiles()`.

**2.** Now write a `Comparator` that uses `File.lastModified()` and pass this, along with the array of files, to `Arrays.sort()`.

**3.** Now create a `Thread` which keeps checking this change after certain delay....

Comment: In the thread inside the run() method, use a boolean controlled while loop , and this will keep running. `while(isFound){}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement your application using Apache Camel. It's made exactly for requests like yours. See http://camel.apache.org/ for an overview.

You basically define routes using Spring DSL or pure Java and route messages to one or many endpoints that are able to act on those messages. For instance fetching files from a local folder and pushing them to FTP as soon as they appear is a one liner. No need to do threading, Java IO fiddling or other stuff you really do not want to take care about.

**Example**

```
from("file://inputdir/?recursive=true&delete=false").to("ftp://user@host../folder/?password=xyz");
```

Comment: Yes exactly, I am doing a push FTP application, I need to send files (News as xml files )to my clients servers as soon as they appear in my server from third parties..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a need for [FileMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html)  or jnotify.