# Java 7 installer for Mac/Windows

Tags: macos, installation, java, java-7

I am programming software in Java 7. The users of the software are not all up to date (especially the Mac users). Therefore I need an installer (Windows/OSX) that can be easily integrated with the software installation. There is a normal installer for Windows 7 so I am especially focused on finding one for the Mac. Bonus points if it can check for XCode and other requirements too).

I am thinking another option would be to just use some of the libraries from Java 7 (for example the file-system library). However, I think this might not be possible due to the version number in the compiled classes? I couldn't use a Java 6 compiler to compile these libraries either (because they are Java 7 code).

I don't think I am the only one with this problem. There must be a solution somewhere, but I haven't found it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Java 7 is not production ready on OS X.  Do not go there.

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?  Why no *nix support?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i need some system relevant data. the last opend data and i want do use the folder-listeners... i am thinking that some strange hacks or no-name-libs for java6 are worse then java 7, or am i wrong? i thinks java7 is coming anyway in the future...

Comment: @AndrewThompson nothing special, could be all done in java6, too.

Comment: Your comment answered ***neither*** of my questions. :(

Comment: @jacob Java 7 is not ready on OS X.  What is so hard to understand about that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, i don't want to use java7 but the alternatives aren't better. i can't get the last opened date of a file in java6 and to listen to folder-changes in java6 you need external libs (without knowing the performance)... file-system-operations are just not easy to implement jet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, a GUI is necessarily for config changes. The main part of the software is done in the background and a system-tray is displayed. _Why no *nix support?_ sry, i do net no "*nix"

Comment: I was going to suggest using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for installing the app., but I don't think it is the tool for installing a tool for the system tray.  I don't understand the last comment, but it doesn't matter now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the best user experience I would recommend using [PackageMaker](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to create a .pkg file which you can then give to your Mac users. That allows them to do a single click-to-install of your app.

Within the package you would bundle your app archive (JAR file), any necessary resources and two scripts, one to check for the existence of Java 7 on the target system, and the other to install it if not found. I would recommend bundling the latest version of OpenJDK7 with your pkg, at least until an official Java 7 SDK is released for the Mac.

Comment: thanks, thats the solution :) now i can use the futures of java 7 without problem ...

Answer (score 2):

JAva 7 is not yet officially supported on Mac OS X, if you are looking for a JAva 7 installer for mac Os X take a look at [openjdk-osx-build](http://code.google.com/p/openjdk-osx-build/) project on Google Code.

Comment: i need to set java_home path to use it, right? there is than a conflict with the old jre... is the old java-jre automatically removed? or how i do that...

Comment: The old JRE is not removed, and there is no conflict ... You can choose the default JRE from System Preferences ...

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** You shouldn't need Java 7 for what your doing.

A better solution is to use Java 6 + Third party JNI libraries (i.e: [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/macos.html),[JavaXT](http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/io/File/Extended_File_Attributes#Last_Access_Time)...)

- [Directory listener in Java using JNotify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941947/515359)

as for **Last Accessed Date** you might need to write tiny bit of Objective-C and pass it back via JNI

- [JNI Development on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2147/_index.html)

---

Mac OS X already comes with Java runtime on Snow Leopard (JRE6)

On Lion it will automatically download JRE6 if application needs it's

[image: via Software Update]

You can of course download preview release of JDK7 from Oracle, but remember this is **preview software** there are some parts still not working yet (for example: Java Web Start)

- [Oracle JDK7u4 Mac OS X Port Developer Preview Release](http://jdk7.java.net/macportpreview/)

**Edit:** Oracle JDK 1.7 Preview Release only supports **Mac OS X Lion**

Comment: thanks, however... openjdk-osx-build sounds better, because not only lion is supported

Comment: @jacob You shouldn't need to package your application with any JDK, it complete overkill. Mac OS X already supports JRE6

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Well then this question already answered :)

Comment: thanks for update, i tried JNotify before, the date is more the prob. Obj-C and JNI would be a solution, however not better then java7 i thought... its just a program for students, they are all java-programmers :D they will need java7 anyway ...