# What is the most efficient way to list a directory?

Tags: java, file, io

So my title might not be the most descriptive but essentially I am doing this in one class:

- Launching a perl script that creates a series of files
- In another function within the same class, I would like to provision certain files that I have created from my first script into another script

  ```
  //process 1
  launchOnCommandLine("perl --arg1 -arg2");
  ```

What the above script does, is that it produces a bunch of files in the current working directory. In a second script what I want to be able to do is retrieve all the output files of extension (.example), retrieve their paths, concatenate them in a comma-seperated list, and feed it into a second script.

```
    //process 2
    launchSecondScript("perl --list-of-comma-seperated-file paths
```

What is the most efficient way to retrieve that comma-seperated string of file paths and provision it to a second function. I also know the directory where the files will be outputted so that is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use a simple Java function to do this

```
private static String concatenateFilePaths(
    String directory, String extension) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  File f = new File(directory);
  if (f != null && f.isDirectory()) {
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
      if (file != null
          && file.getName().endsWith(extension)) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
          sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append('"');
        sb.append(file.getPath());
        sb.append('"');
      }
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

I then might use it like so

```
System.out.println(concatenateFilePaths("/tmp/test/",
    ".example"));
```

On my system `ls /tmp/test`

```
a.example  b.example  c
```

Result of above call

```
"/tmp/test/a.example", "/tmp/test/b.example"
```

Comment: Looks awesome. Is it possible to ensure that this code does not execute before the files are even created? Because if it does, my program will definitely throw an IO Exception as the files won't even exist.

Comment: Wait for process1 to complete, or read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4941869/2970947).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Elliot's response here is a java7 (nio) version

```
public static String listFiles(String dir, String extensionToMatch){

    StringBuilder fileList = new StringBuilder();

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(dir))) {
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            if(path.toString().endsWith(extensionToMatch)){
                if(fileList.length() != 0){
                    fileList.append(",");
                }
                fileList.append(path.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {}

    return fileList.toString();
}
```