# New file inside a directory using java

Tags: java, file, directory

I want to determine if a new file or document is placed inside a specific folder/directory using java. For example, There are no files inside the "C:\Users\User\Documents" directory and then I downloaded a pdf file from the Internet and was placed on the mentioned directory. How can I determine if a new file is detected on the directory using java programming language? (It should also print-out the name of the directory and the new file name).  Can I have any tips on how to create this kind of program using Java language? It should be continuous or in an infinite loop.

I tried this by using this:

```
package readfilesfromfolder;
import java.io.File;


public class ReadFilesFromFolder {

public static File folder = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/My Documents/Downloads");
  static String temp = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Reading files under the folder "+ folder.getAbsolutePath());
    listFilesForFolder(folder);
  }

  public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
      if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {

        listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
      } else {
        if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
          temp = fileEntry.getName();
          if ((temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('.') + 1,        temp.length()).toLowerCase()).equals("txt"))
            System.out.println("File= " + folder.getAbsolutePath()+ "\\" + fileEntry.getName());
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

But based on the outcome, it just accessed the directory but did not list for any new items. Also, it is not yet in loop because I haven't placed it yet. Thank you :) (*Note: I am still new to Java programming :) *)

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941869/directory-listener-in-java)

Comment: use `WatchService` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Comment: Oh thanks :) Gonna read and study that one. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Watch Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html). A watch service that watches registered objects for changes and events. For example a file manager may use a watch service to monitor a directory for changes so that it can update its display of the list of files when files are created or deleted.
A good example can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

You too can use the [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library from the Apache Foundation, mainly the [org.apache.commons.io.monitor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Thank you! :) That will help me a lot to form the program :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the tip! :) I found out how to do this using the WatchService :)

This is the output based on my research and reading :)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    //The path needed for changes
    Path directory = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents");
    //To determine whether a file is created, deleted or modified
    //ENTRY_CREATE can be changed to ENTRY_MODIFY and ENTRY_DELETE
    WatchKey watchKey = directory.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    //This portion is for the output of what file is created, modified, or deleted
    while (true){ 
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
            System.out.println(event.kind());
            Path file = directory.resolve((Path) event.context());
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help other people. Thanks also to those who helped me as well as to the authors of different research materials used to create this one :) Credits to Mr.Kriechel for this one :)